# How to resample a time series?

Tags: python, pandas

With pandas lib, how to transform a time series with steps of one hour to a time series with steps of 5 minutes ?

**Like this**
[image: Time step by hours]

**To this** 
[image]

**To do this I tried to :**

1) Enter the data :

```
import pandas as pd

config = { "00:00": 9, "01:00": 2, "02:00": 0, "03:00": 2, "04:00": 126, "05:00": 1135, "06:00": 5591, "07:00": 10968, "08:00": 7711,
    "09:00": 3287, "10:00": 2652, "11:00": 2964, "12:00": 3959, "13:00": 3293, "14:00": 2625, "15:00": 3009, "16:00": 4563, "17:00": 5853,
    "18:00": 5065, "19:00": 2537, "20:00": 1214, "21:00": 483, "22:00": 211, "23:00": 67, "23:59": 9 }
```

2) Construct lists :

```
list_of_keys = [key for (key,value) in config.items()]
list_of_values = [value for (key,value) in config.items()]
```

3) Construct the pandas.Serie

```
d_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(list_of_keys) 
# Here I don't know if I should use DatetimeIndx or PeriodIndex ...
# p_index = pd.PeriodIndex(d_index, freq='H')

d_serie = pd.Series(list_of_values, index=d_index, dtype='int64')
```

**After that, I do not know how to move forward ...
I tried to use the resample function of the serie but without result.**

Comment: Just as an FYI, stimulating oversampling by a factor of 12 will not create new information. You will never get the second figure from the first as shown unless you manually add noise. At best, you can do some sort of interpolation. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Also, `list(config.keys())` and `list(config.values())`

Comment: This is a good candidate for an XY problem. Can you provide some background?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#create series by dict
d_serie = pd.Series(config)
#convert index to TimedeltaIndex
d_serie.index = pd.to_timedelta(d_serie.index.astype(str) + ':00')
#print (d_serie)

#upsampling with forward filling NaNs
s = d_serie.resample('5Min').ffill() 
#plot bar
ax = s.plot.bar()

#change format of values of axis x
ticklabels = pd.to_datetime(s.index.values).strftime('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))

#solution for many values in axis
#show only each 30th label, another are not visible
spacing = 30
visible = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::spacing]
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    if label not in visible:
        label.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]